# R: how to use the subset option in rpart?

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

From the documentation of `help(rpart)`, there is a `subset` option, which is an "optional expression saying that only a subset of the rows of the data should be used in the fit."

How exactly do I go about using this option?

```
library(rpart)
fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start,
             data = kyphosis,
             subset = sample(1:nrow(kyphosis), 20))
```

In the above code, I randomly sampled 20 row indices from the `kyphosis` data. Is this the correct usage?

Comment: you can always check ```idx = sample(1:nrow(kyphosis), 20); fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start,data = kyphosis,subset=idx) ; levels(kyphosis$Kyphosis)[fit$y]==kyphosis$Kyphosis[idx]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is OK. With `subset`, you can also:

- Explicitly pick rows of your `data.frame`: `subset=1:21`
- Pick rows based on variable(s) value(s): `subset=(Age<50)`